# Как правильно добавлять пост в оригинальные тексты Яндекса?

Tags: индексация, яндекс-поиск

Недавно блог: http://abrek-ad-abra.ru, примерно месяц находился под [АГС](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%93%D0%A1_(%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80)). Курьёз произошёл с оригинальными текстами, которые рекомендуется добавлять, в том виде в каком их будут видеть посетители. И если в коде статьи цитаты были обвёрнуты в:

```
**<pre>`<blockquote> и </blockquote>`</pre>**
```

То при добавление в оригинальные тексты, просто взяты в **" "**, что очень не понравилось Яндексу. После удаления постов из оригинальных текстов и обращения к Платону. Через обновления поисковой базы, санкции были сняты.

Вопрос: Как правильно добавлять  статьи, содержащие какой-либо код или цитаты?

Comment: Мне кажется, об этом нужно у Яндекса спрашивать. Они лучше знают, в каком виде они хотят видеть статьи с кодом или цитатами.